# Cannot use File.delete to remove file

Tags: ruby, batch-file

System:

```
Windows Server 2008
Ruby 192
```

in 'delete': Permission denied Errno:EACCES

the line: File.delete('filename.ext')

If you know any other method to delete the file bypassing this error I'm glad to distribute you some points :) I mean any help would be appreciated ;-p

I was suspecting that file wasn't closed but it is closed.

*Source code:*

```
Dir.foreach(FileUtils.pwd()) do |f|
  a[i] = f
  if a[i].end_with?('log')
    file = File.open(a[i])
    if file.ctime < TIME_TO_REMOVE_LOGS || file.mtime < TIME_TO_REMOVE_LOGS || File.size(a[i]) > MAX_FILE_SIZE
      puts a[i]
      puts file.ctime
      puts file.mtime

      # zipping the file
      orig = a[i]
      Zlib::GzipWriter.open('arch_log.gz') do |gz|
        gz.mtime = File.mtime(orig)
        gz.orig_name = orig
        gz.write IO.binread(orig)
      end
      file.close
    end
  end
  File.delete(a[i])
  i = i + 1
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not closed. The file only gets closed sometimes depending on ctime. There's a lot wrong with your code but the main point is this: be safe with your files and use a block.

```
File.open(a[i]) do |file|
  # access file 
end
# now you don't need to wonder if it's closed.
File.delete(a[i])
```

Also give your variables better names.

Comment: I've already +1'd you for the right answer, but suggest that if you are going to write _"There's a lot wrong with your code"_ that you help this new user out and post what you believe would be better code.

Comment: @phrogz, that's probably true but I didn't feel like rewriting his code. You're welcome to try.

Comment: If you feel that the code is wrong, could you please tell me where to start to improve it? Or What areas of the code are wrong?

Comment: My suggestion is to fix the things I mentioned and then post a new question "what's wrong with the following code" or probably better would be to submit it to codereview.stackexchange.com